# Linear regression between continuous and categorical data

Tags: r, regression, economics

I am trying to run a regression to estimate effect of income level (continuous data) and education (categorical data) on whether a household has received aid. Aid is binary. Is the regular LRM viable given different types of datasets?

MyData:
Aid: 0, 1
Education: 1, 2, 3, .... 16
Income: continuous

What I am trying to do: `lm(aid ~ education + income + education*income, data = mydata)`.
gives quantile error and all zero values

Comment: Hello, you must share a reproducible example with data. i.e. `dput(mydata)`, so the question is able to be answered. In principle, yes, it is possible to modelling such data, possibily you need to use use `factor()`

Comment: There are really two questions here.  The first question is - is the linear probability model (OLS estimated on a binary dependent variable) appropriate at all (or in a particular context).  That is a question that would be better posed on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) since it's not actually a coding question.  The second - what do the errors mean and how do I fix them is a question that could be posed here, but with a reproducible example as @RicVillalba suggests.

Comment: This is a `glm` regression(in particular logistic regression) rather than `lm` regression.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.